# Openlayers WMS Info map.on function

Tags: openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have some doubts when displaying the information of several wms layers in openlayers using the **map.on** function. I show the information in a div perfectly if I click on the layer on the map, but if I click on another area of the map it shows me the empty div, what I want is that it doesn't show me that empty div if I click outside the layer. And I also want it to only show if the layer is visible. Now it shows the same even if the layer is not visible.

```
var demRequest= new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://server:8080/geoserver/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'estations, deep_SHP'},
});
            
map.on('click', function (evt) {
    $('#infos').show();
    document.getElementById('conteINFO').innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution =  (view.getResolution());
    var url = demRequest.getFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate,
        viewResolution,
        'EPSG:3857',
       {
        'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
        'QUERY_LAYERS': 'estations, deep_SHP'
       }
    );
    if (url) {
        fetch(url)
         .then(function (response) { return response.text(); })
         .then(function (html) {
            document.getElementById('conteINFO').innerHTML = html;
        });
    }
});
```

it will always be true that the url exists.

Comment: is it outside the layer, or is there just no data in the layer at that location?

Comment: If you don't want to show empty div, then just check if div is empty, whatever this "empty" actually is. What is the HTML content of such "empty" response?

Comment: @nmtoken If the layer is not visible but I click where the layer should be, it shows me the information. It should not show anything since the layer is not visible, right? @TomazicM The response from the empty div is `<div id="info"><title>Geoserver GetFeatureInfo output</title><style>... </style></div>`

Comment: If a layer  is obscured by another map layer (not visible) but  you request information from that layer through query_layers then the service should provide some response for that layer.  If the layer has no underlying data at that point clicked and the point clicked is within bounds for the layer you will get a null response.